# Display images from local json server in react dynamic with JSX by its src

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, json-server

1. this is one object from 8 objects in my json file.

   ```
        {"name": "Checken", "details": "checken",  "icart": "No",
     "id": 7, "count": 32, "price": 19, "itnum": 1, "src":"./checken.jpg"}
   ```
2. my app component.

   ```
   state = {
        products: []
    }
   async componentDidMount () {
    const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/products");
    this.setState({products: data})

    }
   ```
3. this from my component that render the image by its src.
   I map on the data and make a (p) that points to the object and say that the image src will be from p.src

   ```
   <li><img src={p.src} alt="not found"/></li>
   ```
4. the error is that the images not there so, what I have to do make images appear correctly?.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: the image not there..it is just the alt text

Comment: Can you print `products ` to check what exactly they are after fetching the from remote API

Comment: every thing work but the image not there

Answer (score 0):

you must upload images in internet and put url(link of image uploaded in net) into your db.json file

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your images in the public folder. I just tested and it works.
If it doesn't work for you look in your json file if the "src" of the image is correct